Time formatting in excel - Converting to just hour
I am trying to combine 2 large sets of data produced from 2 pivot tables using a vLookup so the data/graph changes as I use a slicer to filter each table. (The Data sets are not able to be combined) The trouble is in one set of data the time is formatted as HH:MM:SS AM/PM but uses only the Hour not minutes PLUS the AM or PM (which I want as I am grouping data by the hour of the day for the chart, and the other data HH:MM:SS PLUS the AM or PM but uses the exact time i.e.:
Data set 1 23:00:00 PM
Data Set 2 11:24:25 PM
For the life of me I cannot get a helper column to convert Data set 2 to extract and show 23:00:00 PM (with no minutes and seconds) so I can use a Vlookup - I am stupid and its late, any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
I have tried lots of different formatting and custom formatting, also the =Hour function (But for some reason this formula does not copy down the table correctly, Im not sure why)
Data set 1
Data Set 2

Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your problem is in essence that times are just a funny way of displaying decimal fractions of a day. So long as the fraction is there then the comparison is never going to work. Even after rounding you may need a soft test for equality.

Welcome! If possible, could you please show the formula where you're getting #N/A? Also, have you tried something like =VLOOKUP(time_to_lookup,HOUR(times),1)?

Time display is just a different way of displaying a numerical value for a fraction of a day. I can see no obvious reason why vlookup should fail especially in the times in the lookup table are already in the correct order.
Copy your column of raw times to somewhere else and then set its formatting to "general" and you will be able to see the true underlying numerical values.
This simple formula to create a rounded numeric helper cell that is in exact hours may allow you to do what you want. Time assumed to be in A1 enter in B1 the formula.
=INT(A1*24)/24

However a simple compare for equality with the other times in hours will be risky since the reciprocal of 24 doesn't have a clean binary representation (floating point comparisons for equality are always risky with just a handful of exceptions). Rounding errors can cause a lot of trouble. Lookup should be safer but edge effects could put some data into the wrong bin if you are out of luck.
Assuming the other time is in C1 you have to do something along these lines instead:
=IF(ABS(B1-C1)<1e-14, "Match OK", "Fail")

I think you might well be OK if you feed both raw times through the helper rounding routine and then compare those values but I haven't tested it.
